# Prediction for images with different ratios using ultralitycs lib

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov8

I'm using `ultralitycs` lib on python, which is based on `pytorch`.

While reading [the doc](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#inference-sources) I found that I can run a "parallel" prediction of several images using a tensor as:

`BCHW format with RGB channels float32 (0.0-1.0).`

However, I wondered if there is a way to manipulate my images so that I can pass only one tensor even if the images have different sizes and ratios.

**If I resize the images to the same size (to put them in a tensor) I will lose their ratios and this will affect the prediction.**

I use this "trick" to scale them properly when I run my model one image at a time:

```
def correct_size(nd, stride=32):
    corrected = None
    mod = nd % stride
    if mod == 0:
        corrected = nd
    elif mod > (stride / 2):
        corrected = nd + (stride - mod)
    elif mod < (stride / 2):
        corrected = nd - (mod)
    return corrected
    
def predict(self, image: cv2.Mat):
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    if w > h:
        nw = 160
        nh = int((nw / w) * h)
    else:
        nh = 160
        nw = int((nh / h) * w)
       
    nh, nw = correct_size(nh), correct_size(nw)
        
    result = self.model(image,  verbose=False, save=False, imgsz=(nh, nw))
    return result
```